# Set scale level of background map (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, qgis-openlayers-plugin, mapquest

Is there a way to set the scale of the background map in QGIS?
I'm importing a background map from MapQuest via the OpenLayers plugin. I'm creating an overview Map of a whole city, so it is not necessary (and even not wanted) to have named the small roads, which can't even be read when it is exported/printed on DIN A4.

Is there a way to tell QGIS it should take the view of the higher zoom level (where only motorways are labelled)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a less-populated map, you can take the STAMEN layers based on openstreetmap.

Alternatively, you could take a snapshot of a lower zoom level with `Save as Image`, and add that as a raster layer. But you might get a very pixelated view.

BTW I suggest to switch from the openlayers plugin to the QuickMap Services plugin. It works better with the print composer, and is still maintained.

Comment: I would prefer the Stamed Layer as well, but the team decided to choose MapQuest and I can't use another background Layer now :(