# Parts of WMS layer are missing in layout export

Tags: qgis, wms, print-composer

I am having problems with the print composer. A successful printing do not always occur. 
In particular, if the scale is high (e.g. 1:1.300.000), it always fails. 
As you can see some parts of the map are missing.

[image]

If I work with lower scales the chance of a good result increases.

The underlying map is a WMS resource obtained from a regional institution.

Comment: What kind of data sources are you using ?

Comment: the map is a wms resource: 
http://www502.regione.toscana.it/geoscopio/servizi/wms/BASI_TOPOGRAFICHE.htm

the map I am using is: "rt_topogr.topografica50k.rt"

Comment: I am working with version 2.18.3;
open layer plugin has been uninstalled

Comment: This is an issue that can happen with tiled web layers, where one of the tiles doesn't load. When it happens in an export but not in the map canvas, the issue is usually due to the different resolution of the export versus the map. It might help to lower the output DPI, which will force the WMS to give you tiles from a different zoom level. Some of the workarounds listed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309785/81764) might help.

Comment: I second @csk 's comment, I would add one thing which would be to try using the QuickMapServices plugin instead of OpenLayers, it seems to be a bit more stable and more reliable for outputs like this.

Comment: many thanks for the precious advice.
It has worked with quickmapservice