# QGIS large map with high resolution details

Tags: qgis

I am trying to make a map that shows a very large region of southern Ontario but i would like to be able to zoom in on the map once it is created to see fine details such as the names of much smaller roads and streets. 
When i tried to export as a pdf with a scale of 1:5000 with the appropriate map extents the resulting pdf is completely blank (although it takes awhile to save).
When i try to do a similar process in print composer the map scale seems to be different then the print composer scale.
Ive made the print composer sheet very large 20mx10m but it doesnt result in any more detail being shown, it simply is resulting in a larger map.

Comment: What data are you using (Some vector data, or a raster basemap), also a 200m² map will likely be a huge file size and not very practical what are your use case ?

Comment: Google Maps basemap, the application is to be able to send this map off to a group who can see where our sites are located down to the streetnames. We cant export the QGIS map itself to them, the map size at this point was just a random guess, i dont know how big or small the resulting file should be to be able to get the required detail. The biggest issue i think i have is when i change the map extents it changes the map scale and vice versa

Comment: These kind of raster basemap are not really good for print or export (see this for explanation and tips https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/qgis-2-18-quickmapservices-basemap-labels-shrink-when-exported-to-pdf-from-print), you may try  vector tile basemap with the Vector Tiles Reader plugin (https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin/)

Comment: Ok thank you I appreciate your help with this! Ill take a look at those discussions you provided. I hope there is a way to set the scale and map extents to have them locked and not change with each other.