# Problem with map colour when exporting project as picture

Tags: reports

[image]When I export my project as picture TIF our JPEG file, the map change the colours (as you can see in the picture). I can't understand what is the problem here.

Can anyone with the same problem tell me how fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see colour changes, since I don't know, how it looks in your map window. Which software are you working with? How do you export the image? Please add these details **to your question**.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: If your basemap came from WMS your problem is probably similar to this one : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/qgis-2-18-quickmapservices-basemap-labels-shrink-when-exported-to-pdf-from-print/309785#309785 (in short the export fetch different data to match the export resolution setting)

Comment: I'm using Qgis, I exported un incomplete version with no issues. But when I export the final version got this issue with the map colours.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I agree with @J.R. When QGIS starts to make the output it is fetching higher resolution maps from the WMS than it makes for the screen and WMS server is configured to use higher resolution aerial images as source data at large scales. The source data at small scales seems to be some satellite image. If you zoom in with QGIS on that area I believe that at some scale the satellite/orthoimage layer changes in the same way also on your screen. There is not much that you can do, except to print at low resolution, around 70-90 DPI.