# Modify label size of the QGIS basemaps at layout map printing

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, print-composer

I am trying to print out multiple maps in QGIS 3. Each map contains a few points, and should have context information from the basemap such as city names/road names, etc. somehow helpful to find specific locations.

When making just a printscreen, the labels on the maps are somehow visible, but difficult to read. When I am making a map (with the scale, etc..) in the **Layout manager**, the labels become very small,  impossible to read.

How do I adjust a label size into a readable size while printing out the map?

I am currently using the Google Hybrid, OSM standard and Opnvkarte data, but they all have their issues when displaying labels.

They are certainly scalable, and not a raster base, but I am not sure how to address it.

Comment: This is a common complain (for an explanation on why it happen : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/qgis-2-18-quickmapservices-basemap-labels-shrink-when-exported-to-pdf-from-print). If you want full control of your base map I suggest to use vector tile (you may use plugins like MapTiler or Vector Tiles Reader for easy access to vector tile base map)

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.